# Is sed the way to extract a number which is to become part of a command line being constructed?

Tags: sed, ufw

In `/etc/knockd.conf` I want a command that will be a `ufw insert [line number]...` command, the line number is dynamic and can be gotten from finding the first `ALLOW` occurrence in the `ufw status numbered` command output.  I have gotten this far

```
ufw status numbered|sed -n '/ALLOW/p'|sed q|sed 's/].*//'|sed 's/\(\[\)//g'
```

which produces the number I need.  That number it will need to become a mid-part of the `ufw insert` command, to dynamically (virtually) produce this command:

```
ufw insert 5 allow from %IP% to any; ufw reload
```

The `5` above is the example line number of the first `ALLOW` line in the ufw status output.  The `%IP%` is literally in the desired virtual command.

So I would think the command line would begin with the ufw status and sed command combo which produces the line number, and somehow constructs the virtual command and assigns the number into it.  Don't forget the virtual command ends with the ufw reload command.

This is all part of a home surveillance system, headless server running Ubuntu 15.04.  I chose `knockd` because firewall blacklist makers I've seen don't catch and blacklist the perp on the very first probe.  With knockd, I can set a `/etc/knockd.conf` rule to **blacklist a perp's IP based on a single hit from it** on my port 22, 80, 443, whatever I want.  My ufw rules have three sections:

1. Denys of single IPs of blacklisted perps (creating themselves via a `ufw insert 1 deny from %IP% to any; ufw reload` command in `/etc/knockd.conf`),
2. Allows of single IPs of successful knockers (me from my locations, this is the command I need help with because it has to be inserted to the dynamically calculated line after the blacklisted perps),
3. two static denys that cover the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ufw insert $(sed -n '/ALLOW/{s/^.*ALLOW *\[ *\([0-9]\+\).*$/\1/;p;q}' <(ufw status numbered)) allow from '%IP%' to any; ufw reload
```

Comment: Trying.  First try resulted in "ERROR: Invalid syntax".  But I got a fuller sed command to give me the number only.  Will substitute next into your suggested answer....

Comment: my sed statement is a multiple-command sed statement that doesn't want to work so easily.  Trying to refine it....

Comment: Here it is!   "ufw insert $(sed -n '/ALLOW/p' <( ufw status numbered)|sed q|sed 's/].*//'|sed 's/\(\[\)//g') allow from '%IP%' to any; ufw reload".  Mind you, I did not try using the %IP% yet but I'm sure that won't be a problem, right CrazyApe84?

Comment: All of those pipes are unnecessary.  Try this for the sed command `$(sed -n '/ALLOW/{s/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/;p;q}' <(ufw status numbered))` Don't type it out, copy and paste it!

Comment: Neither way is working from /etc/knockd.conf.  But both ways work from the command line.  My guess is that knockd can't execute commands using the substitution within them.  As I'm trying variants, that is what I'm concluding.  I have no hard evidence that it was supposed to work anyway.  I'll try quoting just to make sure...

Comment: BTW @CrazyApe84, your quoting of %IP% needed to be removed.

Comment: I forgot that it was a `knockd.conf` command.  I don't know how that would work exactly.  Maybe you could write it in a bash script that rewrites the entire `knockd.conf` file.

Comment: @kenneth558 Or make the `knockd.conf` command an executable bash script containing the `ufw` command.

Comment: Rewriting the .conf file would require restarting the daemon which would lose any knocking codes in process.  But your second idea has much merit.  I'm getting pulled away from this for now, though.

Comment: @ CrazyApe84 - Your second script idea works fine. Thank you,  CrazyApe84